# how to create logged in session in yii

Tags: yii

i tried using hybrid auth for a facebook login on my yii app, but couldn't get it to work. so decided to work on my own. i managed to get it to retrieve data and store it in my DB. but yii, still doesn't detect user as logged in. here is part of my code in my **controllers/FacebookController.php**

```
    if (app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {

            $user = app()->request->getParam('user');

            Shared::debug($user);
// verify one last time that facebook knows this guy
     if ($user['id'] === app()->facebook->getUser()) {

                    if (!empty($user['email']))
                    {
                        $model = User::model()->findByEmail($user['email']);
                    }   
                    else if (!empty($user['username']) && empty($user['email'])) //incase we don't get an email, we use a facebook email
                    {
                        $email = $user['username'].'@facebook.com';
                        $model = User::model()->findByEmail($email);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $model = false;
                    }

                    if (!empty($model)) 
                    {

                        // facebook email matches one in the user database
                        $identity = new UserIdentity( $model->email , null );
                        $identity->_ssoAuth = true;
                        $identity->authenticate();
                        if ($identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
                            print_r($identity);
                            app()->user->login($identity, null);
                            echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'success' => url('/')));
                            app()->end();
                        } 
                        else {
                            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'System Authentication Failed', 'code' => 'auth'));
                            app()->end();
                        }
                    }
```

in my code above, when i `print_r($identity);` the object below is echoed. and FYI, the email `xxxxxx@facebook.com` is stored in the DB but `app()->user->isGuest()` still returns true. what am i doing wrong here?

```
UserIdentity Object
(
    [_ssoAuth] => 1
    [_id:UserIdentity:private] => 19
    [username] => xxxxxx@facebook.com
    [password] => 
    [errorCode] => 0
    [errorMessage] => 
    [_state:CBaseUserIdentity:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail

Instead of passing a null into `app()->user->login($identity, null)` try passing in a duration like

```
$duration = 3600*24*30; //30 days

app()->user->login($identity, $duration);
```

I have had problems setting duration to 0. Not sure why either. But this worked for me before

Comment: yeah duration 0 didn't work for me either :( anyone have any ideas?